# Animation fall down XML

Tags: android, xml, animation

I have to make some animations in my app. First of all my Image must go to the bottom of layout, then it must appear on the top of layout and go to default(first) position. Like this:

[image]

i have this code:

**push_down_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
<translate
  android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
  android:toYDelta="0"
  android:duration="2000"/>
</set>
```

**push_down_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
<translate
  android:fromYDelta="0"
  android:toYDelta="100%p"
  android:duration="2000"/>
</set>
```

but it doesn't work correctly

Comment: what does not work correctly?

Comment: animation starts from top and goes to the bottom... then it disappears and appears on the default position.

Comment: and if its not ok, how can we help you?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but maybe someone needs this.
You should add  `android:fillAfter="true"` in your code. Here's the example if you want to leave the view on its position:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
<translate
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="100%p" />
</set>
```